# JavaScriptで追加した要素にjQueryでclassを追加する方法

Tags: javascript, jquery

JavaScriptで要素を追加した後に、追加した要素がクリックされるとjQueryでclassがつくようにしたいのですがどうしたらいいのでしょうか？
以下のコードが動かなくて困っています。

HTML

```
<h1>テスト</h1>
<div id="test"></div>
```

JavaScript&jQuery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function(){
  'use strict';

    function show(){
    var div_element=document.createElement("div");
    div_element.id="hogehoge";
    div_element.innerHTML='あいうえお';
    var parent_object=document.getElementById('test');
    parent_object.appendChild(div_element);
  }

  addEventListener('load', function(){
    show();
  });

  $("#hogehoge").on("click", function(){
  $("#hogehoge").toggleClass("hogehoge");
  });

})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

おそらく（実際に試していません）`.on`が実行される時に`"#hogehoge"`（で示す要素）が存在しないことが原因かと思います。

jQuery で以下の様な感じでいいと思います。

```
<script>
$(function(){
    'use strict';

    $("#test").append("<div id='hogehoge'>あいうえお</div>");
    $("#hogehoge").on("click", function(){
        $("#hogehoge").toggleClass("hogehoge");
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

処理の実行順が誤っています。

`addEventListener`で登録している`window.onload`イベントは該当HTMLおよびHTMLから参照されている画像その他のリソースが全て読み込まれたときに発生します。これに対して、

> $("#hogehoge").on("click", function(){
>   $("#hogehoge").toggleClass("hogehoge");
>   });

このステートメントは`<script>`タグ内の通常の呼び出しで実行されるため、HTMLを先頭から順に解析していって、該当タグが読み込まれたタイミングで実行されます。なのでこの時点で`window.onload`は発生しておらず、`#hogehoge`にマッチするエレメントも存在しません。

なので該当処理を`show()`の直後に行うか、あるいは`jQuery.on`のオーバーロードを使用して

```
$(document).on("click", "#hogehoge", function(){
    $("#hogehoge").toggleClass("hogehoge");
});
```

とその時点で存在する親要素に対して`"#hogehoge"`セレクターを指定して`jQuery.on`を呼び出す必要があります。

Answer (score 1):

解決されましたか？？
さくっとスニペット作ってみましたので確認してみてください｡
※クラスが付加されていることを視覚的に確認するために､CSSで色をつけています｡

```js
$(function(){
  'use strict';

  function show(){
    var div_element=document.createElement('div');
    div_element.id='hogehoge';
    div_element.innerHTML='あいうえお';
    var parent_object=document.getElementById('test');
    parent_object.appendChild(div_element);
  }
 
  // 動的に追加したDOMにはon()を使う必要があります
  $(document).on('click', '#hogehoge', function(){
    $('#hogehoge').toggleClass('hogehoge');
  });

  show();

});
```

```css
.hogehoge {
  color : red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <title>toggleClass</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='test'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```